# Programming for Windows: Simple SFTP Transfer Application

Tags: c#, java, .net, windows, sftp

I've never worked on a Windows application before. I now need a simple application that will add a context menu to files with a specific extension. When you click the context menu, the application will connect to a remote linux server via sftp, ask for credentials and upon successful authentication, transfer the selected file to the server.

The application needs to be compatible with Windows XP onwards.

Which language / platform can I use to quickly develop this application? What tools do I need? How do I register the context menu item? And how would I distribute it?

Any guidelines would help.

Answer (score 1):

You need a shell extension and an application that will do the actual transfer job. The shell extension will just start the application with parameters.

For shell extensions C++ is a natural choice. Use of .NET for shell extensions can cause different problems discussed many times.

For an application you can use virtually anything - SFTP client components exist for .NET and for C++ (mainly ActiveX controls). I would not recommend Java though - it is quite heavyweight for a small program such as yours.

Answer (score 0):

To create the context menu entry: Create a COM-ShellExtension with VB6. This one just calls the upload app when a file is selected.

To do the upload: Just call a command line sftp client from your COM app, and let this do the upload. CopSSH comes to mind, but I don't know if they hae sftp on board.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can find almost everything you need at codeproject's "Microsoft All-In-One Code Framework" page; it seems to document how to do what you're asking assuming i understood correctly that you want to create a context menu in explorer.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CSShellExtContextMenuHand.aspx

edit: to clarify; this is for a .NET solution, the examples i saw on the front page are c#